# Dynamic dashboard schema

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

**A little background about our app...**

We have a survey app where each client has their own custom surveys, each with their own custom questions.

Because all the questions are custom, it is impossible to have a standard dashboard that shows any deep insight into their surveys responses.

So, each client will have to have their own personalized dashboard.

Take, for example, a medical practice. Let's say they have 5 surveys. Each survey asks the patient to rate their physician. In this case, their dashboard might have a dashboard metric for physician rating. Whereas other clients would have metrics based on their questions.

**A possible starting place**

My first thought is to have table(s) with dashboard definitions for what should be displayed.

**Help us!**

Are there any design/schema patterns that I should be looking into? Any recommendations would be helpful, and much appreciated!

Comment: I suggest using nosql databases. see what their schemaless approach can offer you.

Comment: I have done such design using nested form blocks reassembled using recursive queries. Laravel’s ORM will probably not allow you to perform such queries.